# Дизайн и шаблоны страниц на сайте с Django

Tags: html, css, django

Добрый день! Я не веб-программист, но мне потребовалось создать сайт за короткий срок. Раньше был опыт только с WordPress, но там мне почти не приходилось работать с дизайном сайта -- достаточно было установить шаблон и исправить кое-что в PHP-коде под собственные нужды. Теперь я решил воспользоваться Django, т.к. есть опыт разработки на Python. Однако имею мало представления о создании "скелета" страниц и дизайна для сайта. Какими средствами (связанными с Django или отдельными, вроде Twitter Bootstrap) лучше воспользоваться для создания хороших html и css для страниц сайта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django предназначен для разработки сложных сервисов "с нуля". Возможно, для Вашей задачи лучше взять какую-то готовую CMS на ее основе? (см. [варианты](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/), например)

Comment: Возможно, но сначала хочется попробовать написать без использования CMS. Мне интересно, какими средствами обычно пользуются при разработке дизайна и разметки. Т.е. вручную ли писать все html и css, или есть способы получше (исключая готовые шаблоны)?

Comment: Возьмите тот же bootstrap - он с Django почти никак не связывается. Кроме, разве что, форм (django-crispy-forms красиво работают)